# Remove checkout top link magento

Tags: php, html, css, xml, magento

I want to remove the Checkout link from my magento store: [www.iphonemadness.nl](http://www.iphonemadness.nl) because i use a one page checkout. But i can't remove it, i tried to delete it in but this doesn't work.

I also tried to add this at local.xml:

```
    <reference name="top.links">
        <remove name="checkout_cart_link" />
        <block type="checkout/links" name="checkout_cart_link_custom">
            <action method="addCartLink"></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
```

Comment: Dont add it in local.xml. Try to comment the code in checkout.xml where <reference name="top.links">. Comment the whole reference block. Dont forget to clear the cache once it is commented. It will work and I just tried it

Answer (score 1):

It seems you install the onepagecheckout plugin.
Please refer to the onepagecheckout.xml from this plugin to remove item instead of origin one.

Also, you module should run depends on that plugin.

Comment: Since I cannot read Dutch, I cannot make sure which one you want to remove. However, from what I do before. The plugin define some layout change in "onepagecheckout.xml" for the layout in "checkout.xml". If the module you define load before the onepagecheckout module or they change the define of what you want to remove, The change you make will failed.